# HSDC database connection

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have to inject data in a database via a Java program.
I use Hibernate and also Thread (pool of thread via Executor) because the customer want a quick software.
I use a pool of thread .
The program works well during 45 seconds - 1 minute and after i have this error, repeated and repeated :

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-593" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1463)
    at fr.msa.agora.bp0gos.qualification.structure.InjecteurFluxStructureRFOSImpl$UnitOfWork.run(InjecteurFluxStructureRFOSImpl.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:840)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
```

Here is my code :

```
@Service("InjecteurStructure")
    public class InjecteurFluxStructureRFOSImpl extends AbstractInjecteurFluxRFOS implements     InjecteurFluxRFOS {

        private final StructureRFOS2StructureGOSMapperImpl mapper;

       @Autowired
    public InjecteurFluxStructureRFOSImpl(final StructureRFOS2StructureGOSMapperImpl pMapper,
            final SessionFactory pSession, final Executor pPoolDeThread, final GestionRepertoire pGestionRepertoire) {
        super(pSession, pPoolDeThread, pGestionRepertoire);
        mapper = pMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void mapUnFichier(final File pFichier) {
        final RFOSStructure structureFichier = JAXB.unmarshal(pFichier, RFOSStructure.class);
        persisterTable(structureFichier.getSTS());
    }

        private void persisterTable(final STS pStructureSTS) {
        final UnitOfWork unit = new UnitOfWork(mapper, sessionFactory, pStructureSTS);
        poolDeThread.execute(unit);
    }

    private static class UnitOfWork implements Runnable {

               private final StructureRFOS2StructureGOSMapperImpl mapper;

                private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

                private final STS structureSTS;

                public UnitOfWork(final StructureRFOS2StructureGOSMapperImpl pMapper, final SessionFactory pSession,
                final STS pStructureSTS) {
            mapper = pMapper;
            sessionFactory = pSession;
            structureSTS = pStructureSTS;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            try {

                final fr.msa.agora.bp0gos.metier.sts.domaine.STS structureGOS = mapper.map(structureSTS);

                final Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                try {
                    session.save(structureGOS);
                    session.flush();
                    transaction.commit();

                } catch (final RuntimeException r) {
                    transaction.rollback();
                    throw r;
                } catch (final Error error) {
                     transaction.rollback();
                    throw error;
                }
            }  finally {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance everybody,
  Thomas

Comment: Comme indiqué dans un autre post,j'ai rajouté dans mon Fichier de configuration Hibernate ceci :

Comment: hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50

Comment: Like mentionned in the forum (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606674/java-cannot-open-connection), i add in the Hibernate configuration file these instructions :


    hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
    hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
    hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50

But it leads to the same problems.
Sorry for the comments, i became "mad", i write in my mother language instead of english.
I am sorry.
I wish a nice day to everybody,
  Thomas

Comment: It sounds like you've used up all your connections, how many `UnitOfWork` objects are you creating (and running)? If it's any more than 20 then I think you're going to run into issues.

Comment: Jamey,
I thank you for your answer.
In fact, there are 97331 XML files,
then the mapUnFichier method is called 97331 times
and finally the persisterTable method is called 97331 times.
Consequently, there are 97331 UnitOfWork created.
I believed it was good.
You think it is too much ?
What can i correct my code please ?
Thank you Jamey,
 Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

- hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20

This parameter has the following documentation:

> hibernate.c3p0.max_size This is the maximum number of connections in the pool. An exception is thrown at runtime if this number is exhausted.

Obviously if you have 97331 simultaneous connections you are going to trigger the exception mentioned above which is, I imagine, exactly what is happening. I would suggest limiting your `ThreadPool` to also only have 20 simultaneous threads running at a time. This depends on your use case though. For example, if you are running the sort of application which is just starting up, performing this job and then closing down, then the method I suggested will work fine. However, if your application is a long running application (perhaps a webapp) and requires other database connections happening from other users, then I would suggest setting the ThreadPool max a lot lower (perhaps 10), and ensuring the c3p0 limit isn't breached in another way (by having too many users connected at once, or too many of these jobs running). Upping the c3p0 limit will help as well. I have a feeling there's no point going higher than 100, but I can't remember exactly why, sorry.

Comment: Jamey, i thank you a lot for your solutions. I will try to implement the solution you propose.

Comment: No worries, please remember to accept this as an answer if it works for you. ;)

Comment: Jamey, i added this instruction in my code : "poolDeThread = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);" . 
I created a pool , setting to 20 the maximum number of threads running.
But i suppose that i have also to change my code. Because if i do not change my code, i will have my 97331 tasks to be executed.
Thank you a lot, Thomas

Comment: Like you said, i limit the number of simultaneous thread : How can i indicate that you have resolved this problem ? Nice day.

Comment: Hi, "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.", check out this link for full info: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . :)